# file upload in sharepoint sandboxed solution

Tags: 2010, sandbox-solution

I need help regarding file uploading in sandboxed solution. In a thread in this portal somebody gave the following link as a  solution to this problem:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

but this is also not working for me. The webart  is throwing exception:

> Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's
>   Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error
>   has occurred.

Can you please guide me how can I beat this? I have been pulling my hair out for days, your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My upload widget in SPWidgets ( http://purtuga.github.com/SPWidgets/ ) will work for this.  As a matter of fact, it was developed using office365 as my development environment.
The download file (zip file) contains an all inclusive demo webpart (CEWP) that you can import into your office 365 site and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to build a Silverlight app uses the Client Side Object Model to upload the file. You can then wrap the silverlight in a webpart or use the built-in Silverlight webpart and put you .xap in it.

A potential problem is that the maximum file size is limited to a very low amount, one typical workaround is to [change MaxReceivedFileSize](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/9c633e9a-8633-4baa-a379-cbfbc9d1b470) on the server, which you will not be able to do of course, but I think Office365 has set a larger value, you'll have to verify that.