# Adding Image to folder programatically

Tags: list, web-part, file-upload

I am developing a web-part (a form basically) with the following functions:

1. Generate a `SPListItem` with info taken from `textboxes` *(i.e save data in a database table)*.
2. Generate a folder using the `ID` of generated `SPListItem` obtained in previous step *(in a separate library)*.
3. Select image with `FileUpload` control and save it in the generated folder *(step 2).*
4. Press button `Save` for call Click event which contains the following code:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Button Click event.
   /// </summary>
   protected void btnSaveData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           using (SPSite _site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
           {
               using (SPWeb _web = _site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl))
               {
                   //Library who contains the folders (included the new folder to generate).
                   SPList listaImagenes = _web.Lists["FolderLibrary"]; //It's just an example.
                   //_folder.
                   SPFolder _folder = null;
                   #region Step N. save image in generated folder.
                   try
                   {
                       if (_folder != null)
                       {
                           if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                           {
                               _folder.Files.Add(FileUpload1.FileName, FileUpload1.FileBytes);
                               _folder.Update();
                           }
                           else { lblMsg.Text += "<b>There's no file selected</b> <br/>"; }
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           lblMsg.Text += "La _folder es NULL. <br/>";
                       }
                       //Save changes.
                       _folder.Update();
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex) { lblMsg.Text += "Error. " + ex.Message + "<br/>"; }
                   #endregion
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           lblMsg.Text += "Error: " + ex.Message + " <br/> Stacktrace: " + ex.StackTrace;
       }
   }
   ```

The first two steps are complete, however, after pressing the button `Save`, the code checks if the `FileUpload` control has a file (i.e. `FileUpload1.HasFile()`) which is always `false.`

I already check another questions about [`FileUpload` control for save images in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=fileupload%20is%3Aquestion) in the provided code in most of those questions the shared code doesn't show if they use Session variables or another way of keep the selected file in `FileUpload` control.

So my full question is:

How can keep the selected image and use it for add it in folder programmatically?

**EDIT:**

The Web-Part is a `Sanboxed solution` and the `FileUpload` control isn't in a `UpdatePanel` control.

Comment: Are you developing this solution as sandboxed solution or farm solution?

Comment: Is your FileUpload control inside an Update Panel control?

Comment: @Pro.. **Sandboxed solution** _edited to my question._

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri No. _edited to my question_

Comment: You cannot get file item operations using sandboxed solution. Once I have had the same issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [file upload in sharepoint sandboxed solution](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38866/file-upload-in-sharepoint-sandboxed-solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandbox Solutions do not support FileUpload or HtmlInputFile controls, you need to change it to a Farm Solution

Reference

[SharePoint 2010 Sandboxed Web Parts does not support file uploading](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/SharePoint-2010-Sandboxed-Web-Parts-does-not-support-file-uploading.aspx)

But have a look at following question

[file upload in sharepoint sandboxed solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38866/file-upload-in-sharepoint-sandboxed-solution)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no support of FileUpload in SharePoint sandboxed solution. It's the limitation.

If you want to achieve the same you need to do compromise with browser compatibility by following below links:

[Uploading attachements to SharePoint link using SPService](http://sympmarc.com/2014/05/27/uploading-attachments-to-sharepoint-lists-using-spservices/)

[Attachment Upload Using SPServices](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72950/attachment-upload-using-spservices-and-not-the-js-file-api)

Though these links are for attaching file to the list item. So as per my thought we can handle how to add files to folder in SharePoint library with the help of [FileReader API](http://caniuse.com/filereader).

I have raised similar [question](http://sharepoint-community.net/forum/topics/attach-file-to-list-item-in-sharepoint-2013-sandboxed-solution) in SharePoint community as well, but I got no response so I had to compromise with browser compatibility.

Hope this helps!